# Is it would be possible to use Google Cloud Powershell to manage instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

I don't have an engineering or coding background, so I will try to keep it simple.

I use Google Cloud for preemptible instances. There is about 10 instance and as you know after a while instances closes themselves. Opening and re coding everything is little bit exhausting.

My question is; I use the same commands to put instances to work.

Can I use GCloud Powershell to give commands to all 10 instance at once?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [instance groups](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/). You can address a fleet of VMs as a single entity. Plus, with a managed instance group, you can have preemptible instances [automatically re-added](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible#preemptible_with_instance_groups) when capacity is available.

Cheers!

Comment: Hey James, I've created an instance group but can't seem to find to how address a fleet of VMs as a single entity?

Comment: Any idea how can I do that? @James